# How to indent second line of an item in list environment?

Tags: lists, indentation

I have a bullet point list that I think would look a lot better if I could indent the second line of some of the points. This really shouldn't be hard, but I can't seem to manage. I've tried `\hspace` and a few other things. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{list}{\labelitemi}{\leftmargin=1em}
        \item \texttt{type} --- ablah bblah cblah \\ 
        this line should start right under ``ablah'' above
            \end{list}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you want to indent the second line by the length of the item label, `\labelwidth`.  Second, you want to further indent it by the length of the words `\texttt{type}---`.  The command `\phantom` does this.  Thus we get the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{list}{\labelitemi}{\leftmargin=1em}
        \item \texttt{type}---ablah bblah cblah \\ 
        \hspace{\labelwidth}\phantom{\texttt{type}---}this line should
        start right under ``ablah'' above 
            \end{list}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add space at the beginning of a line you need to use `\hspace*{}`.  The normal `\hspace{}` is ignored at the beginning of a line.

Alternatively, I would recommend using [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [$\bullet$ \texttt{type} ---] ablah bblah cblah
        \item [] this line should start right under ``ablah'' above
     \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter! Both \hspace* and enumitem might come in handy later. (I'll try to remember to up-vote your answer when my reputation allows it :)