# in Beamer, how to remove left margin/indent of a description list

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, margins, indentation

I have a two column frame with a plot one the left, and a description list on the right

```
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Figs/fig1}
      \end{center}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{description}
      \item[$E_{t,i}$] The $i$th transmitted signal vector
      \item[$E_{r,i}$] The $i$th received signal vector
      \item[$E_{err,i}$] The $i$th error vector
      \end{description}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
```

However there is a big spacing between the figure and the list, and it is due to the left margin of the description list. I tried to remove it by following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56813/14127) and set the `leftmargin` and `labelindent` parameter to zero or even negative numbers, but it didn't work. How can I remove the spacing?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to adjust the space `beamer` reserves for the description label, using the optional argument to the environment:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Figs/fig1}
      \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{description}[$E_{err,i}$]
      \item[$E_{t,i}$] The $i$th transmitted signal vector
      \item[$E_{r,i}$] The $i$th received signal vector
      \item[$E_{err,i}$] The $i$th error vector
      \end{description}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(See `beamer` manual, p. 113 for v. 3.27.)

Comment: It works, but it does not work with the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to shift the left column by hand (of course you would have to to do this on every slide on which you encounter this problem)

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Figs/fig1}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
        \hspace*{-2cm}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            \begin{description}
                \item[$E_{t,i}$] The $i$th transmitted signal vector
                \item[$E_{r,i}$] The $i$th received signal vector
                \item[$E_{err,i}$] The $i$th error vector
            \end{description}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```