# Creating a list

Tags: lists

I have to create a list of abbreviations. In the list, I have to write the short form on the left side and the fullform on the right side. I don't need a fancy style of creating this list of abbreviations. I just want to do it in the normal text format.

**PROBLEM:** The spacing between the left side and right side is uneven. I need a list as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Packages `acro`, `acronym`, `glossaries` .... all do that

Comment: isn't there any simple technique to write the text ..I don't want the abbreviations to get highlighted in the document.

Comment: You've been a while here already: The magic word is `MWE` ;-)

Comment: [Make the lines of a description item line up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155432)

Comment: Also [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33818)

Comment: Have you tried the *description* environment: `\begin{description}\item[AC]...\end{description}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , Andrew:  It is giving me the desired results to some extent but the spacing between lines is too much. In the image that I have posted, the spacing between lines is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `description` environment with the customizations described in [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width/33818#33818), just add a `noitemsep` to the options of the list as well, to remove the vertical space between each item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=6em,style=nextline,noitemsep]
  \item[AC] Salient object \ldots
  \item[OpenCV] Open Source \ldots 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```