# Simple chronology using the description environment

Tags: lists, description, chronology

I'd like to create a simple chronology/biography such as those you see sometimes in books:

[image: simple chronology]

The most straightforward way that comes to my mind is by using the `description` environment. But if I try this:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[1809] Nasce il 19 gennaio a Boston, secondo figlio di una coppia di attori girovaghi; poco dopo il padre abbandona la famiglia.
\item[1811] Alla morte della madre viene accolto in casa di Frances a John Allan, mercante di tabacco a Richmond, in Virginia. Allevato come un figlio (di lì il secondo nome, Allan) non viene però adottato legalmente.
\item[1815-20] Per motivi commerciali, la famiglia Allan si trasferisce a Londra. Edgar frequenta scuole private, dal 1818 la Manor House School a Stoke Newington, vicino a Londra (a cui si ispirerà per parti di \textit[William Wilson]).
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The result if far from optimal:

[image: output]

The text is too close to the labels, and when the label content is longer (like in the third item above) the text gets pushed forward. I need to increase and "normalize" the distance between labels and text.

Would it be possible to achieve what I want just by using `description`?

Comment: [Make the lines of a description item line up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155432)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth =4.5em, leftmargin =\dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep\relax]
\item[1809] Nasce il 19 gennaio a Boston, secondo figlio di una coppia di attori girovaghi; poco dopo il padre abbandona la famiglia.
\item[1811] Alla morte della madre viene accolto in casa di Frances a John Allan, mercante di tabacco a Richmond, in Virginia. Allevato come un figlio (di lì il secondo nome, Allan) non viene però adottato legalmente.
\item[1815-20] Per motivi commerciali, la famiglia Allan si trasferisce a Londra. Edgar frequenta scuole private, dal 1818 la Manor House School a Stoke Newington, vicino a Londra (a cui si ispirerà per parti di \textit{William Wilson}).
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]